# How to fix else statement in Live search with JSON and JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a code of Live search with JSON and JQuery.
It searches information form JSON file, I need to add `else` statement if search word is not in data and show a message.

I added `else` statement but it gives messages as many as total entries in JSON data.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();
        var myExp = new RegExp(searchTerm, "i");
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
            var output = "<ul>";
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    if (val.name.search(myExp) != -1) {
                        output += '<li>';
                        output += ' ' + val.name + ' ';
                        output += '</li>';
                    } else {
                        output += '<li>';
                        output += ' no data ';
                        output += '</li>';
                    }
                }

            });

        output += "</ul>"; $('#update').html(output);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Data file:

```
[{"name":"hello"},{"hello 2"},{"hello 3"}]
```

When I type 'world' which is not in data, it shows  "no data" message 3 times (how much entries I have in data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is your JavaScript code is invalid. There is an extra `}`. I removed it. The second and main problem is that you add "no data" message to output for every entry you look (if your search term matches) in your JSON data. So, try this code:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val(),
        myExp = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i');
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        var found = false,
            output = '<ul>';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if (val.name.search(myExp) != -1) {
                found = true;
                output += '<li>';
                output += ' ' + val.name + ' ';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output = found ? output : (output + '<li> no data </li>');
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#update').html(output);
    });
});
```